# How can I organize TestCafé tests into multiple steps?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am testing a large project with long scenarios (some with more than 100 interactions with webpage). I would like to break them down into shorter steps that run in sequence (like in Mocha) but I don't know how to do that.

Example: In a single test, I would like to run

```
fixture('test1')

test('test1', async (t) => {
  ...login
  ...createSubAccount
  ...modifySubAccount
  ...activateSubAccount
})
```

where each of the steps would show in console and in report. Right now, the only thing I know how to do is to put each step into its own `test()` context, but that means that if e.g. `createSubAccount` fails, `modifySubAccount` and `activateSubAccount` will still run (even though the workflow already failed). Also, there is the unhappy part that each `test()` clears the browser (but I can deal with that).

In short: How can I split the tests in a way that if a single substep of `fixture` fails, the whole `fixture` fails immediately? Or similar thing, but for `test()`?

Also, I don't want the whole pipeline to end on the first test failure, as would happen with `--stopOnFirstFail` flag - I want to run all the tests, to find which are failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestCafe does not support the functionality you require at the moment. The only solution I could think of is, as you proposed, to implement your test as a fixture with steps as tests, use [disablePageReloads feature](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3945#issuecomment-507211138) (NOTE: it is experimental), track the number of passed tests manually, and check it at the beginning of each test. It is a bit tedious, but it should work as you need.

Another solution that has not been implemented yet and the easiest way to split the long test into steps is to simply divide it into functions. The only issue that may arise is related to reporting. Even if you implement a custom reporter, there is no possibility to pass information about the steps into it (you can vote for the [corresponding feature request](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3584)).

Also, I would like to draw your attention to [Page Model](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/concepts/page-model.html) pattern. This can shrink your tests and make them more readable.

Please open a [new feature request](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md) with a comprehensive description if you have a better idea of how this should be done.

Answer (score 3):

`test()` is the smallest unit. The idea is it's an independent piece of testing code, e.i. a bunch of test steps. This doesn't change no matter what tool you use (TestCafe, Playwright, Puppeteer, Cypress, mocha, Jest, ...).

And so:

> Right now, the only thing I know how to do is to put each step into its own test() context, but that means that if e.g. createSubAccount fails, modifySubAccount and activateSubAccount will still run (even though the workflow already failed).

seems like breaking one of the main principles of tests, that is they are independent. **Don't split test steps that belong together between different tests.**

If the only drawback now is the length of your test, why don't you do it like you hinted at in the example:

```js
test('test1', async (t) => {
    login();
    createSubAccount();
    modifySubAccount();
    activateSubAccount();
});
```

you can create functions for login, createAccount etc. and then use only such function in your tests, which would make them as short as shown here. You can also easily create various scenarious:

```js
test('activate account without modification', async (t) => {
    login();
    createSubAccount();    
    activateSubAccount();
});

test('create account', async (t) => {
    login();
    createSubAccount();   
});

test('create account without login', async (t) => {    
    createSubAccount();   
});

// and so on
```

It doesn't even look that long.

Comment: I know I can do this, however I will only see this in code and not in the report - and that's my problem. I would like to have checkmark in report for every step that executed properly.